# How to disable the Wide Tile for SecondaryTiles in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application in Windows Phone 8. Having set of Tiles in my Home screen and these tiles can be pinned as a SecondaryTiles in the Windows Start screen.

Basically i am using FlipTileData to create the SecondaryTile in my application. But as per my requirement, i should not be having any Wide Tile option for the SecondaryTile. SecondaryTile must be pinned as Small and Medium tiles.

I set the following properties in FlipTileData.

```
var secondaryData = new FlipTileData
{
    Title = "Content",
    BackgroundImage = //Image Uri,
    WideBackgroundImage = // Image Uri,
    SmallBackgroundImage= // Image Uri
};
```

Is it possible to achieve this in Windows Phone 8. Could you please help me on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn disable the wide-tile when you call `ShellTile.Create` with that secondary data.
Do this by setting the `supportsWideTile` argument to false. See [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207919%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more info.

```
ShellTile.Create(
    launchUri,
    secondaryData,
    false);
```